# Web to Case Question

Tags: email, web2case

If you click "reply" button on a case, the "***From***" field will be set to your email add / email add of the user who will reply on the case. The question is, is there a way to set it to our customer service email rather than our personal emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruct your Support reps to change their personal email address in the "My Email Settings" page to your customer service email adderss

Comment: this answer also applies to Email2Case

Comment: @cropredy - correct, it will work the same for all cases regardless to the Case origin/source

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the input @LihodRachmilevitch & cropredy .